# Twig_Error_Syntax, The function 'render' does not exist in 'base.html.twig'

Tags: routes, syntax-error, twig, silex

I have this working on my home environment, but not on my work one. All changes pushed to git so I have the same source code. Composer update run on the composer.json file so the dependencies should be the same too.

My services.php file contains the TwigServiceProvider, SessionServiceProvider, and UrlGeneratorServiceProvider.

My composer.json file contains:

```
"require": {
"silex/silex":               "~1.2",
"twig/twig":                 ">=1.8,<2.0-dev",
"doctrine/dbal":             "~2.3",
"symfony/security":          "2.6.*",
"symfony/translation":       "~2.6",
"symfony/config":            "~2.6",
"symfony/yaml":              "~2.6",
"symfony/twig-bridge":       "2.3.*",
"ircmaxell/password-compat": "~1.0.3"
```

}

and my base.html.twig which is causing the error contains:

```
<body>
{% include "./partials/top_bar.html" %}

{{ render(path('sidebar')) }} <!-- THIS APPEARS TO BE THE PROBLEM -->

<!-- Main Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</div>

{% include "./partials/scripts.html" %}
{% block additional_scripts %}{% endblock additional_scripts %}
</body>
```

I have a route that is registered (YamlLoader and have added the controller as a service) and looks like this:

```
### component routes
sidebar:
  path          : /admin/sidebar
  defaults      : { _controller: 'controller.includes.sidebar:action', _locale: 'en' }
```

I hope this is enough information for you guys. I've had a look around and i've not found something that works :( The route itself works if you travel to it so I'm almost certain the routing is correct, which leads me to believe it might be related to a package version or a missing package.

Comment: First things first, you say the dependencies *should* be the same. Just open the *composer.lock* and check the versions of *twig/twig* and *symfony/twig-bridge*, make sure **they are the same**

Answer (score 0):

Probably you get this message, because it really does not exist? I do not see any line of code where you register this function. Twig has a pre defined set of [functions](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/index.html). `render()` is non of them, so you would need to [extend twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html) first.

**Extending Twig (Function)**

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('function_name', function () {
    // ...
});
$twig->addFunction($function);
```

Or since you mentioned you are using Silex:

**Extending Twig Service Provider (Function)**

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views',
));

$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function($twig, $app) {
    $function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('function_name', function () {
        // ...
    });
    $twig->addFunction($function);
    return $twig;
}));
```

As it seems you really want to render a certain twig template, I think there is a missunderstanding. You can use **render()** in PHP to render a certain template with parameters as array.

```
echo $template->render(array());
```

Rendering a template within twig will be done by just including it.

```
{% include 'template.html' with vars %}
```